# TypeScript - Inline function not getting checked for type safety

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and trying few things

*where* function demands number parameter and bool as return value.

```
function where(items: number[], filter: (item: number) => bool) {
    for (var counter = 0; counter < items.length; counter++) {
        var item = items[counter];
        if (filter(item)) {
            console.log(item);
        }
    }
}
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Case 1 - TypeScript gives a compile error

```
var evenFilter = function (item: number) {
    //actual line is item % 2 == 0;
    return item;
}
where(data, evenFilter);
```

Case 2 - Inline function with incorrect return type does not generate compile time error

```
where(data, function(item : number){
    return item;
});
```

Case 3 - Even the short hand syntax does not generate compile time error

```
where(data, item => item);
```

Is this a bug with TypeScript or expected behavior?

Comment: Not really an answer but it generates an error if you specify the return type of the inline function: `where(data, function(item : number):number{ return item; });` ... but not if you don't.

Comment: Logged bug on [CodePlex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1021)

Comment: These samples are against version 0.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments received on [codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1021), both case 2 and 3 are bugs.

1. Case 2 is fixed in version 0.9.0
2. Case 3 is under investigation

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug. Apparently anonymous functions are not type checked. Functions assigned to variables / named functions are. You can open a bug report here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

I searched through the repository and could not find a similar bug report.

**Just me rambling**
Perhaps type is not inferred unless you assign to a variable or name the function. This assignment should take place when we are invoking a function as well (as you are assigning a parameter a value) but type inference is not kicking in for that  bit.